# What happens when MDM vendor certificate expires?

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management

There is no way to renew the MDM vendor certificate,you just have to create a new one.
After I create a new one, the devices have to be re-enrolled.
Is there a way I can avoid re-enrollment of devices?
I want to know what happens to the enrolled devices when the MDM vendor certificate expires?

Answer (score -1):

If APNS certificate expires you have to enroll the devices. APNS certificates are valid only for an year.

Here is how you can renew APNS .

https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/renew-apns-certificate/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Note that the question is asking about a different type of certificates; you might want to revise or delete your answer so that it addresses the question. In any case, the answer should not depend on external links which might break.